# scanf skipped (tried adding space and \n)

Tags: c

I am trying to file redirection a text document and have my code read it and output the number of characters present in the code and allowing the user to input a letter non-case sensitive that instructs the program to look through the text and return with the number of times the letter appeared.

The scanf is not working correctly and does not get user input.

I've tried to add a space like this: " %c" and "%c\n".
Tried removing & and using getchar();

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Defining variables

#define SIZE 8000

int main(void)
{
        char case1 = 'a', case2 = 'b', data[SIZE];

        int i, count;

// Reading in the .txt file into a 8000 sized array and removing any other unnecessary portions from the array.
    for (i = 0; i < 8000; i++)
    {
        fscanf(stdin, "%c", &data[i]);
    }

        printf("The text from the file: \n\n");

    for (i = 0; data[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", data[i]);
    }

// Printing out the .txt document and counts the number of characters
        printf("\n");
        printf("There are a total of %i characters in that text.\n ", i+1);
        printf("Enter a character to search for in the text:\n ");

// Exiting from stdin.

        if (!freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin))
    {
        perror("/dev/tty");
        exit(1);
    }

// Asking for user input.

        scanf("%c", &case1);

// Converting user input into different lettercase.


    if (case1 == toupper(case1))
    {
        case1 = tolower(case1);
    } else
    {
        case2 = toupper(case2);
    }
        printf("This is your input: %c. Also searching for:  %c.\n", case1,case2);

// Searching the text for user-inputted letter.

    for (i = 0; data[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == case1)
        {
        count++;
        }
        else if (data[i] == case2)
        {
        count++;
        }

    }

        printf("That letter %c appears a total of %i times.\n", case1, count);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What command did you use for text redirection? It seems to work for me when I used command `cat <textfile> | ./<executable file>`

Comment: I used ./a.out < <textfile>

Comment: I tried that and it seems to work also. Could you try compile the entire code snippet I edited above in a separate file and rerun the command again? The issue could be in a different part of your code that is not shown here.

Comment: Include the code you "tried" too.

Comment: Includes full code. Apparently adding in the code from the section // Exiting from stdin allowed scanf to work, can someone explain, I know it exits from stdin but what does that mean? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fscanf()` on `stdin` which is equivalent to `scanf()`.  If your 8000 character input does not end in a newline, `fscanf()` will not return until there is a newline, and whatever has been input after the 8000 characters will be accepted into `case1` in the final `scanf()` call.

That is the `scanf()` call is not "skipped", rather it reads a character already in the buffer.  If that character is not whitespace, the "fixes" you tried will be inadequate.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    fscanf(stdin, "%c", &data[i]);
}

// Flush all remaining input up-to next newline
int c ;
do {} while( data[SIZE-1] != `\n` && 
             (c = getchar()) != `\n` && 
             c != EOF ) ;
```